# WLAN Management via Managed Wifi API

Tags: c#, windows, wifi

I have a need to manage the wireless network connection of Windows tablet devices. The tablets are running Windows 8.1 Industry.

I've found Managed Wifi API which appears it should make this task easier. Using the provided sample however I'm unable to simply connect to a network.

No matter what I try the same exception is raised:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in ManagedWifi.dll
Additional information: The parameter is incorrect
```

I can list SSIDs and explore them. I thought that by exporting a wireless profile (as snippet below) and using that as the profileXml for connection via the API would work, but the same error occurs.

```
netsh wlan export profile xxxx folder=c:\
```

C# Code below:

```
            // Connects to a known network with WEP security
            string profileName = "xxxxx"; // this is also the SSID
            string mac = "4254487562332D50575147";
            string key = "xxxx"; //this is my passphrase
            string profileXml = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><WLANProfile xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1\"><name>{0}</name><SSIDConfig><SSID><hex>{1}</hex><name>{0}</name></SSID></SSIDConfig><connectionType>ESS</connectionType><MSM><security><authEncryption><authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication><encryption>AES</encryption><useOneX>false</useOneX></authEncryption><sharedKey><keyType>passPhrase</keyType><protected>true</protected><keyMaterial>{2}</keyMaterial></sharedKey></security></MSM><MacRandomization xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3\"><enableRandomization>false</enableRandomization></MacRandomization></WLANProfile>", profileName, mac, key);

            wlanIface.SetProfile( Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profileXml, true );
            wlanIface.Connect( Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Auto, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Any, profileXml);
```

Can I be pointed in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point:

Use windows to connect to the network. Make sure to tick "connect automatically".

Go to

> \ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces\

and find the profile, which was created for your new connection.
Copy the XML into your code and replace the dynamic portions.